# How to determine what's the file type

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, file-type

I use ASIHTTPRequest to download file. The url is like http://www.aaa.bbb.com:8000/showuploaddocument.aspx?docid=45. So I am not able to determine the file type through the url. How can I determine the file type of the downloaded file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the Content-Type header returned by the server:

```
NSString *contentType = [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"Content-Type"];
```

This will be a string like image/jpeg, text/plain, etc.

Comment: I think this is the better answer

Answer (score 0):

I do think you are only getting streams of data (raw data) in the end you choose how to consolidate that into something meaningful. Like:

```
NSString *aString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Or:

```
UIImage *aImage = [UIImage imageWithData:myData];
```

Comment: Doesn't the stream also give a MIME type in its header?

Comment: Depends of the URL he has. In the worst case, just put the data inside aString and NSLog it and see what you have in there.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLResponse has methods for that like

```
- (NSString *)MIMEType;
- (NSString *)suggestedFilename;
```